# Behaviour of symlinks

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link

I successfully and not successfully created a symlink:

I have two directories

```
~/foo
```

and

```
~/bar
```

Now I have a file called `baz.txt` in this path `~/foo`. My aim was to create a symlink in `~/bar` so I can access it from there as well.

With following command which I executed in the directory `~/foo`:

```
ln -s baz.txt ~/bar
```

I got a *bad* symlink which got marked red. The results weren't as I expected and I tried something else which eventually worked out for me.

I executed this command in the path `~/bar`

```
ln -s ~/foo/baz.txt .
```

I wonder now why my first approach didn't work since I referenced my file to the directory where I want to have my symlink. It looks to me like I did the same thing in both commands just in different directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is absolute versus relative paths. An absolute path is `/bar/foo/file.txt` and a relative path is `./file.txt`. When you run `ln -s foo.txt /home/ubuntu/central_addcontent/program/`, that is equivalent to running

```
ln -s ./foo.txt /home/ubuntu/central_addcontent/program/
```

This will create a file called `foo.txt` that is pointing to `./foo.txt` *in the target directory*. This is simpler to illustrate with an example giving a different link name:

```
$ ln -s foo.txt /home/terdon/central_addcontent/program/bar.txt
$ ls -l /home/terdon/central_addcontent/program/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 7 Nov 25 11:25 bar.txt -> foo.txt
```

As you can see above, `bar.txt` is pointing to `/home/terdon/central_addcontent/program/foo.txt` and that file does not exist. To do this correctly you can either use the full path of `foo.txt` or use the relative path but with respect to the target directory. Both of these will work:

```
$ ln -s ~/central_app/program/foo.txt ~/central_addcontent/program/
$ l /home/terdon/central_addcontent/program/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 40 Nov 25 11:28 foo.txt -> /home/terdon/central_app/program/foo.txt
```

Or

```
$ ln -s ../../central_app/program/foo.txt ~/central_addcontent/program/
$ ls -l /home/terdon/central_addcontent/program/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 33 Nov 25 11:29 foo.txt -> ../../central_app/program/foo.txt
```

In the second example, I've used a relative path but with respect to the link's target.

Comment: So what I did in my first example was a reference to the same file over and over again ?

Comment: @IbrahimApachi exactly. It was a link linking to itself. On my system, I can create the link but when I try to read it I get "Error: too many levels of symbolic links". It basically goes into an endless loop.